# How do point clouds become polygons?

Tags: 3d, point-cloud

I have reached some limits in my game experiments that seem to be solvable by working with content as 'point clouds'. My main concern now is how to convert the resulting point clouds into polygon meshes? I can't seem to find any algorithms anywhere, but I see people doing it in various programs, so it is clearly possible.

EDIT: Some elaboration. I am doing some simulation of, among other things, geological forces, and a polygon surface simply does not allow the needed detail. My goal is to create a landscape as a point cloud and use that to better simulate forces on it. But the changes are expected to be so complex that simply starting with a flat polygon surface and warping it will not be useful. So I need to taake the point cloud landscape and create a polygon surface for it, from the data it holds.

Comment: Do you want to ask about rasterization or triangulation?

Comment: Probably triangulation, but I am open for both ideas!

Comment: You probably need a hull-finding algorithm as well.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you (or your artist) uses a modelling program and makes **models**. These already contain the information about the order they are in. This can be either done by indexing them (having an array, that basically says in which order they come, like `0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2` for a quad) or by repeating them in the vertex list. The latter is usually only used when you want to have sharp edges, because you can't define a vertex and a normal vector separately.

There are however procedurally generated meshes. Those need to be triangulated using one of the algorithms, like [Delauney triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

GPUs always use triangles to draw things, because there are already a lot of optimized algorithms to draw them. Some APIs allow you to render quads or polygons, but those functions are deprecated, because GPUs have to triangulate them every frame, which is ineffiecient.

After you have a the vertices in order, you have to rasterize them. Rasterization is the process of converting points to triangles. [This is also a pretty optimized](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html). Most games don't do this part, they instead rely on an API such as OpenGL or DirectX, which can communicate with the GPU.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how to program your game to do it.

Comment: @HenryStone This is a Q&A site designed to help fixing problems in already existing codebases or provide algorithms, we don't give tutorials, because there are already thousands of them

Comment: I am not expecting tutorials, only an insight in a topic I do not yet fully understand. If this goes against policy, I will not object to the question being closed.

Comment: "GPUs always use triangles". This is wrong. You can also use quads natively in some cards (which also has it advantages, it often has a nicer topology). Although its not that widely supported anymore. And, with geometry shaders, you can do certain isosurface extractions directly on the GPU.

Comment: @Polygnome This was either a long time ago (e.g. the Saturn distorted sprites to achieve polygonal effects, and those were quads) or you're speaking about the quads rendering mode in some APIs, in which case you should read my answer properly

Comment: @Henry well, you take the points, put them in an order, where every trio defines a triangle and draw those triangles. There's not much to say to it. You can use APIs like DirectX or OpenGL, they abstract the triangle drawing away from you or you can just use the draw polygon or draw triangle method if whatever engine/framework you use.

Comment: The issue is that I work without a premade engine, which means that understanding how one can find the right trios is basically black magic to me. Otherwise, yes, you would be totally right. I just happen to be completely new to point clouds.

Comment: @Henry again, most model formats already store that. Look at how a wavefront file is built, and how you can process that, or try looking into implementing some sort of triangulation algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The process of converting data (for example, point clouds) into polygons is called **meshing** (since you produce a *mesh*) or *Isosurface extraction*. There are lots of techniques out there - marching cubes, marching tetrahedrons, surface nets, greedy meshing, dual conturing and many, many more. If you look for "Isosurface extraction", you'll find lots algorithms with different stenghts and weaknesses. Without knowing more, its hard to ecommend an approach.

For starters, marching cubes is a safe bet, though.

Comment: Thanks, that is a big help!! I use marching cubes already and love it, my problem is that the next version of my program does not limit points to a 3d grid, and I have never dealt with pount clouds as free floating clouds. It is very far from dealing with a rigid grid...

Comment: You don't need a 3d grid for marching cubes. But as I said, without knowing more about your exact problem its hard to recommend any approach.

Comment: I have never seen Marching Cubes used in any other way than to represent a 3D point grid (heck, i used to do it myself for kicks). Do you have links to examples / explanations?? Also, I will explain my problem better in an edit in a moment...

Comment: @HenryStone Sure, the end result with Marching cubes is an isosurface whose vertices only conincide with a 3D grid. But the point cloud can be arbitrary (it doesn't need to be a point cloud that conincides with a 3D grid, it can be of arbitrary density and distribution), you only need to have the proper weighing function, and it needs to be in a structure that can be efficiently queried (e.g. KD-tree).

Comment: Do you have examples? Thinking about this in the abstract is too much for my brain, I never saw MC as anything but a visual representation of grid values, and my brain can't let go of that...

Comment: @HenryStone You can do it trivially by pre-computing the scalar field and weighing it for the points you need. But thats a bit lossy w.r.t. the normals of the isosurface facets, doing it on-the-fly allows for some optimizations not present in the original MC. You only get artifacts when the point cloud is undersampled in some areas (when you don't have enough vertices to sample for the given cube). You can also do apadtive resizing of the MC grid to sample more dense areas finer if you want to. Its really not magic. I might have some links on my old laptop, but finding those will take time.

Comment: Sorry, the grid / MC connection is so ingrained in my mind that I cannot picture it without something visual. I tried, I swear. A link to an example, a key phrase to google, anything will help...